# Cloudify 2.7 and Openstack Icehouse

Tags: openstack, cloudify

Can I configure Cloudify 2.7 with Openstack Icehouse?

I can configure the VM management with the Havana cloud driver but I can not release any application. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Cloudify 2.7 was tested with Openstack Grizzly and Havana; Icehouce wasn't released at the time. Still, it should work on Icehouse since the Openstack APIs are backward compatible.

To understand the issued on your specific environment, please refer to Cloudify's [support forums](https://cloudifysource.zendesk.com/home) and supply more details.